# PHPMailer Body gets truncated

Tags: phpmailer

I'm having some strange issues with PHPMailer. I'm trying to send some content which I generate with PHP in HTML and plain text, but the body gets truncated. What's even stranger is that this happens only to the email I generate, if I put in there some generic content in much greater length, it gets sent properly. I must also mention, I did echo the content of both `$content` and `$nohtmlcontent` variables and everything is there like it should be, but when I receive email into my mailbox, it's truncated.

My PHP code for creating plain text and HTML email body:

```
$content="<BODY bgColor=\"#ffffff\"><FONT face=\"Verdana\" size=\"2\">";
$content.="Hello $name.<br /><br />Administrator of <a href=\"http://$url\">$url</a> has created a new account for you.<br /><br />Your new account details:<br />";
$content.=$message."<br /><br />";
$content.="If you see something wrong, please reply with correct details and we will update your account.<br /><br />";
$content.="Have a nice day,<br />$url</FONT></FONT></BODY>";

$nohtmlcontent="Hello $name.\n\nAdministrator of $url has created a new account for you.\n\nYour new account details:\n\n";
$nohtmlcontent.=$usrEmail."\n\n";
$nohtmlcontent.="If you see something wrong, please reply with correct details and we will update your account.\n\n";
$nohtmlcontent.="Have a nice day,\n$url";
```

All variables are populated with proper data.

My PHPMailer code for sending email:

```
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail=new PHPMailer(true);
try {
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
    $mail->SetFrom('admin@example.com', 'example.com');
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Subject = "New account for you";
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->AltBody = $nohtmlcontent;
    $mail->Body = $content;
    $mail->Send();
    return true;
}catch(phpmailerException $e){
    trigger_error("PHPMailer failed: ".$e->errorMessage());
    return false;
}
```

Result:

```
Hello 12 23.

Administrator of admin.localhost.dev has created a new account for you.

Your new account details:
Username: user1
Password: 123456
E-Mail Address: info@tourazore.com
Subscription Status: Not Verified (you must verify your email address before you can use your account)
Package: Free (limitations: 1 tour, 5 items)
First Name: 12
Last Name: 23
City 34
Country 45

Your verification link: http://admin.localhost.dev/verify-account/882672636ce2ad8c498f75a9b836ff055aecf573/

If you see something wrong, please reply with correct details and we will update you
```

Expected result:

```
Hello 12 23.

Administrator of admin.localhost.dev has created a new account for you.

Your new account details:
Username: user1
Password: 123456
E-Mail Address: info@tourazore.com
Subscription Status: Not Verified (you must verify your email address before you can use your account)
Package: Free (limitations: 1 tour, 5 items)
First Name: 12
Last Name: 23
City 34
Country 45

Your verification link: http://admin.localhost.dev/verify-account/882672636ce2ad8c498f75a9b836ff055aecf573/

If you see something wrong, please reply with correct details and we will update your account.

Have a nice day,
admin.localhost.dev
```

Please notice the extra content in the end.

I have also tried using PHP's function `mail()` to send the same content, it also gets truncated.

Any ideas?

**SOLUTION:** The PHP code generated really long line, after adding a few newline characters, the complete content got through.

Answer (score 1):

Also this may not be related but you're using Body and not MsgHTML

```
$mail->Body = $content;
```

But it looks like your using HTML expressions in your content.

I'm fairly new to this but from what I've read to use HTML in PHPMailer you should use

```
$mail->MsgHTML = $content;
```

Although your text looks likes it is displaying fine and you solved your problem. But I thought I'd share incase it helps.

Some useful info here
https://phpbestpractices.org/
 (scroll down to email info)

and here:
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: I never noticed that there's a `$mail->MsgHTML` available, on all examples (and SO questions/answers I saw) I always noticed `$mail->Body`, but `$mail->IsHTML(true)` must be provided prior, otherwise PHPMailer presumes that the content is plain text and the wrong `Content-Type` is sent.